# How to access global variable in function hook in javascript?

Tags: javascript-objects, javascript

I want to use global variable 'x' in the below hook funcion.

```
var x = 10; //global variable

var oldA = a;    

a = function a(param){

    alert(x);        //showing error: x is undefined 

    return oldA(param);

}
```

How to resolve the error?

Comment: also you should look around [Scoping and Hoisting](http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting.html)

Comment: @user1671639: the function assigned to `a` _cannot be hoisted_ here, as it's an expression. The only thing that gets hoisted here, are the variable declarations

Comment: Are you in `node` environment? In that case, try `global.x = 10;` & `alert(global.x)`. Actually, polluting global object is not a good idea. But, you might want to try it.

Answer (score 14):

Your code works fine for me, but you might want to resolve `x` to the global variable explicitly by using `window.x`.
When not in a browser environment, or an environment where the global object isn't called `window`, try:

```
(window || root || global || GLOBAL || this || self || {x: undefined}).x
```

The `{x:undefined}` object literal is just to make sure the expression doesn't throw up errors.
I've listed pretty much all names I know of that are given to the (strictly speaking nameless) global object, just use the ones that might apply to your case.

On the other hand, if the global variable `x` *might* be reassigned by the time the function (`a`) gets called, a closure would be preferable:

```
a = (function (globalX)
{
    return function a(param)
    {
        console.log(globalX);
        return oldA(param);
    };
}(x || window.x));//pass reference to x, or window.x if x is undefined to the scope
```

Of course, if you're in strict mode, you need to be careful with implied globals, too.
That's all I can think of that is going wrong with your code, some more details might provide us with a clue of what's actually happening...

Comment: @user1671639: thx. And I wouldn't call your comment _a mistake_, because the variable declarations _are_ hoisted, after all. With the OP's snippet as is, `oldA` will be `undefined`, and `oldA(param)` will throw an error either way. Providing the OP with a link on hoisting is a nice contribution either way.

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem
`( root || window )` throws error in mozilla firefox console.
`ReferenceError: root is not defined`

Comment: @Mohammed if course, `root` is an alias for the global object in nodeJS. In browsers, just use `window`

Answer (score 0):

To access global Js variable inside function, don't use Var in function scope and mention var in global scope. 
Eg.

```
<script>
    var foo = "hello";
    function fxn() {
        alert(foo);
        foo = "bai";
    }
    fxn();

    alert(foo+"out side");
</script>
```