# Please explain the output of the given code

Tags: javascript

The code is given below:

```
  function a() {
    function makeWorker() {
        this.ename = "Pete";
        return function() {
            console.log(this);
            console.log(this.ename);
        };
    }


    var work = makeWorker();
    work();
}
 var ename = "John";
a();
```

this.name outputs to "Pete".but i have defined another variable ename in the global scope.So why is "Pete" printing instead of "John"?.The  program is running in non-strict mode.

Comment: @MiHawk: Where is hoisting coming into play here?

Answer (score 2):

`makeWorker` is kind of redundant here if `a()` is called without a `this` anyway, so let’s replace the call to `makeWorker` with what it does:

```
function a() {
    this.ename = "Pete";
    var work = function() {
        console.log(this);
        console.log(this.ename);
    };
    work();
}

var ename = "John";
a();
```

and replace the call to `work` with what it does:

```
function a() {
    this.ename = "Pete";
    console.log(this);
    console.log(this.ename);
}

var ename = "John";
a();
```

and replace the call to `a` with what it does, assuming again that `this` is the global object:

```
var ename = "John";
this.ename = "Pete";
console.log(this);
console.log(this.ename);
```

So you set the global `ename` to `"John"`, then set it to `"Pete"`, then print it and the result is `"Pete"`. Nothing weird. It might help you to log something when each assignment happens in the original code:

```js
function a() {
    function makeWorker() {
        console.log("Setting ename to Pete");
        this.ename = "Pete";
        return function() {
            console.log(this.ename);
        };
    }

    var work = makeWorker();
    work();
}

console.log("Setting ename to John");
var ename = "John";
a();
```

Comment: Great explanation

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you are executing the makeWorker and it is simple overriding the variable ename, and you are wanting to access a global variable.

Check out this article. 
[How to access global variable in function hook in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17363548/how-to-access-global-variable-in-function-hook-in-javascript)

Comment: If all of the relevant details in your answer are provided in a link to another SO post, then this question should be closed as a duplicate of that post. You should flag it as such.

Answer (score -2):

There are several different scopes, in JavaScript. The variable ename is created within the scope of the function. To access the global scoped variables you have to call them a different way.

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp

Comment: To access the variable at a global scope when you created a variable at the local function scope you have to call it using the window.{variableName}, in your case window.ename

Comment: You should never have to post a comment to your own answer in order to add details. You always (regardless of reputation) have the ability to edit your own questions or answers. Please do so.

Comment: This answer is just wrong. There is no `ename` variable in any function scope here.